# Negative integer to signed 32-bit binary

Tags: python, python-2.7, binary

```
>>> a = -2147458560
>>> bin(a)
'-0b1111111111111111001111000000000'
```

My intention is to manipulate `a` as 32-bit signed binary and return it. The correct conversion for `-2147458560` would be `'0b10000000000000000110001000000000'`; how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

*Bitwise AND* (`&`) with `0xffffffff` (2<sup>32</sup> - 1) first:

```
>>> a = -2147458560
>>> bin(a & 0xffffffff)
'0b10000000000000000110001000000000'

>>> format(a & 0xffffffff, '32b')
'10000000000000000110001000000000'
>>> '{:32b}'.format(a & 0xffffffff)
'10000000000000000110001000000000'
```

Comment: and then I must convert it back to to return it.

Comment: @Nikos, to `int`? Simply `a & 0xffffffff`

Comment: `bin(-2 & 0xffffffff)` returns `'0b11111111111111111111111111111110'` as expected. However, `bin(2 & 0xffffffff)` returns `'0b10'`. Do I have to write a custom code to make it return `'0b00000000000000000000000000000010'`?

Comment: @frederick99, You can use `str.format`: `'{:032b}'.format(2 & 0xffffffff)` / `'0b{:032b}'.format(2 & 0xffffffff)`

Comment: How do I get from `'0b10000000000000000110001000000000'` back to `-2147458560` ?

Comment: `int('0b10000000000000000110001000000000'[2:], 2)` will give you `2147508736`, `struct.unpack('i', struct.pack('I', int('0b10000000000000000110001000000000'[2:], 2)))[0]` will give you `-2147458560`.

Comment: why do you and it with 0xffffffff? does that number have an important property?

Comment: @CampbellHutcheson, `0xffffffff == 0b11111111111111111111111111111111 == 2 ** 32 - 1`, `a & 0xffffffff` was used to only get last 32 bits.